What is the correct php type for fields with TCA type json?
I want to store some options in the DB like this:
    'question_options' => [
        'exclude' => false,
        'label' => 'xxx',
        'description' => 'xxx',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'json',
            'default' => ''
        ],
    ],

What would the correct type for my Model.php be?
/**
 * questionOptions
 *
 * @var string ?? array ?? object ?? mixed ??
 */
protected $questionOptions;

Array shows null and string gets escaped when setting it through a setter.

?string = ''. Extbase does not have yet support for TCA Type JSON and handling. YOu need to implement a method in your model to get the decoded value / write it again (json encoded) to the string. At least I guess. never tested it. That needs to be investigated and finished (as feature) - needs someone to work on that.

For the getter you can return an array if you implement json_decode() there. The setter is getting a string as parameter usually. If you decode the json in the setter or getter doesn't matter so much as long as you use the getter also for internal usage. So if you use string or array for the class-property depends on where you implement json_decode().

Of course you can just return a string with the getter instead, but then you've to decode it perhaps in every location where it's used.

The problem when using setter that gets passed a string my json gets escaped e. g. wrapped in quotation marks and all other quotation marks are escaped like this \". "{\"1\": \"a\", \"2\": \"b\", \"3\": \"c\", \"4\": \"d\"}"

I can confirm that using the setter causes the described problems. Does anybody have a solution for that?

You could make use of TYPO3's TypeInterface which will get raw data passed as constructor argument by the DataMapper. This works similar for the PropertyMapper which does this via the CoreTypeConverter.
This allows you to use classes which implement the TypeInterface as type for domain model properties. In this particular case you can automatically convert the raw JSON string to an array-like structure like this:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Package\Domain\Data;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Type\TypeInterface;

final class JsonData extends \ArrayObject implements TypeInterface
{
    public function __construct(string $jsonString)
    {
        $data = json_decode(
            json: $jsonString,
            associative: true,
            flags: \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR,
        );

        parent::__construct($data);
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return json_encode(
            value: $this,
            flags: \JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR,
        );
    }
}

Your domain model can now use this as property type:

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\Package\Domain\Model;

use Acme\Package\Domain\Data\JsonData;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity;

final class Example extends AbstractEntity
{
    public ?JsonData $data = null;
}

Now all instances allow you to transparently access the already decoded JSON data. Assuming an object $example1 of this Example model which has {"foo":"bar"} as data in its tx_package_domain_model_example.data column:
$example1->data['foo'];

{example1.data.foo}

You can see a real-life implementation of this in the pagemachine/typo3-formlog package:

Domain/Data/JsonData.php
Domain/Model/FormLogEntry.php


Does the Extbase property mapper work with this? Or is there a way to make it work?

For this the CoreTypeConverter exists, so the behavior is the same. I've amended my answer.
